# Laravel if input equals to zero write placeholder

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to write this line of code in blade laravel so that if `Input::get('query', '')` equals to zero writes 'Document name' (placeholder) else it writes in value `Input::get('query', '')`.

```
 <input name="query"  type="search"  value="{!! Input::get('query', '') !!}" placeholder="Document name" id="inputSearch">
```

I tried:

```
<input name="query"  type="search"  value="@if (Input::get('query', '') != 0) {!! Input::get('query', '') !!} @endif" placeholder="Document name" id="inputSearch">
```

Help pls?

Comment: `(Input::get('query')` will return true when it has query input else it will return false so you do not have to compare with 0

Comment: try this `value= {{(Input::get('query')) ? (Input::get('query')) : ""}}`

Comment: I have to compare to zero because zero is hardcoded search

Comment: Excellent Adam it works! Thank you. I just needed to put double quotes like this: value="{{(Input::get('query')) ? (Input::get('query')) : ""}}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
value= "{{(Input::get('query')) ? (Input::get('query')) : ""}}"
```

Comment: You just have to put double quotes around like this: value="{{(Input::get('query')) ? (Input::get('query')) : ""}}"

Comment: oh yes, i forgot that

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`blade`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#displaying-data) syntax:

```
value="{{ Input::get('query') or '' }}"
```